# Punteros en lenguaje c

Tags: c, punteros

Podrían ayudarme a entender que hace la siguiente línea de código, o que significa

```
float (*x (int *a)) [20];
```

Comment: En estos casos uso [Revisión de Declaraciones C](https://cdecl.org/). Ahi ingresas una declaración y te la explica (en inglés). Para tu caso, dijo: *declare x as function (pointer to int) returning pointer to array 20 of float* **Declara x como una función (que recibe puntero a entero) y retorna un puntero a un arreglo de 20 floats**

Comment: Gracias 

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de leer una declaración compleja es pensarla como una expresión que
al evaluarse tiene el tipo a la izquierda. Por ejemplo:

```
int *x;
```

En este caso es sencillo, `*x` desreferencia a `x`, y se evalua en un entero.
Por lo tanto `x` es un puntero a int.

Otro más complejo:

```
char *y[10];
```

Aca `[10]` tiene mayor precedencia que `*` así que a primero se accede a un elemento de `y`,
luego se lo desreferencia y por ultimo se obtiene un char. Entonces `y` es un arreglo de
longitud 10, de punteros a char.

Aún más complejo:

```
int (*t (float *r)) [11];
```

En este caso hay dos identificadores, podemos empezar por cualquiera, pero lo hago con
`r`. Se desreferencia `r` y se obtiene un float, por lo tanto `r` es un puntero a float.
Con `t` seria así: Se llama a `t` con un puntero a float (`r`), luego se desreferencia el
resultado. Del resultado se accede a un elemento de tipo int. Por lo tanto, `t`
es una función que recibe un parámetro `r` (puntero a float), que devuelve un puntero
a un arreglo (de 11 elementos) de enteros.

[Aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=vs-2019) hay una tabla (en inglés) con la precedencia de los operadores de C de mayor a
menor (los operadores con mayor precedencia se evaluan primero).